# Some words won't be stemmed using tm ("easier" or "easiest")

Tags: r, text-mining, tm

I have large questionaire dataset where some of the features need to be stemmed, with the goal being to assign a topic to each response. However, I'm having trouble stemming some words using the package `tm`.

Here is a reproducible (simplified) example:

```
library(tm)

# Words that need to be stemmed
test_vec <- c("easier","easy","easiest","closest","close","closer","near","nearest")

# Preprocessing function to clean corpus
# Note that, this is my full pipeline, but only the last command will be used in this case example
clean_corpus<- function(corpus){
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers)
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords("en"))
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus,stemDocument)
    return(corpus)
}

# Create corpus with test_vec
test_corpus <- VCorpus(VectorSource(test_vec))
# Apply cleaning
test_corpus <- clean_corpus(test_corpus)

# Print out stemmed values
for(i in 1:length(test_corpus)){
  print(test_corpus[[i]]$content)
}

[1] "easier"
[2] "easi"
[3] "easiest"
[4] "closest"
[5] "close"
[6] "closer"
[7] "near"
[8] "nearest"
```

**Question 1**
Why isn't  `[1] "easier"` and `[3] "easiest"`  stemmed to be `"easi"` (like `"easy"` has been). Similarly, why isn't `"close"` or `"near"` stemmed. Am I missing something?

**Question 2**
This is a side question, but is there a way to relate words like `"close"` and `"near"` from a dictionary that would be able to verify that these are synonyms. If they are synonyms, all instances of `"near"` will then be changed to `"close"`, for example.

Comment: The most common stemming algorithm is the [Porter-Stemming Algorithm](http://snowball.tartarus.org/algorithms/porter/stemmer.html). These algorithms aren't prefect because they just look at the characters and have no idea what the word really is. So if you follow the steps of the algorithm, you'll need that no transformation occurs for those words. Of you have words that you want to manually transform, you'll have to do that yourself or write your own stemming algorithm.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516681/why-the-results-of-the-porter-stemmer-algorithm-that-i-have-not-in-accordance-wi

Comment: @MrFlick Then which algorithms are prefered? I struggle to believe that this problem has not been solved by some package out there, because it's so basic to text mining. Therefore, I'm assuming I must be missing something.

Comment: @MrFlick The only possible manual way I can think of is to use a stem output, like `"easi"`, to loop through all strings in the corpus and when a string contains that stem, then I would set that string equal to the stem value. For example, `"easier"` and `"easiest"` both contain the stem `"easi"` and will therefore be overwritten as `"easi"`. The problem with this is it will be computationally expensive and burdensome because I have to locate all the stems. Hope this makes sense?

Comment: There is no perfect algorithm. The English language it not well suited to character based analysis. You seem to be asking for something that simply does not yet exist. If you want to more generally ask about natural language processing a better place to do that would be [datasciense.se] or [ai.se]. If you want to understand word meaning, then stemming isn't going to help you.

Comment: I agree. But that's the thing, this isn't about the semantics. I'm simply trying to get the "root" words. An algorithm doesn't need to know what "easy","easiest", or "easier" means. It should just be able to determine that they both belong to the same class because they have, for example, mutaually inclusive character strings.

Comment: This might exist in the form of a sort of dictionary database. But english has plenty of irregular words, so it will take some extra knowledge to know that "easier" can be stemmed to "easy" but that "financier" cannot be stemmed to "financy."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple stemmers (quick overview [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introduction-to-stemming/)), but porter is used the most. Python also has Lancaster stemming which would return the following based on your `test_vec`:

```
easier easy
easy easy
easiest easiest
closest closest
close clos
closer clos
near near
nearest nearest
```

But still there are issues as `iest`, is not shortened.

But you could also use lemmatization which would return the following:

```
library(textstem)
lemmatize_words(test_vec)
"easy"  "easy"  "easy"  "close" "close" "close" "near"  "near"
```

For topic assignment lemmatising might be preferred to stemming because it groups better. But you need to be aware of the differences between both.

Lemmatisation (or lemmatization) in linguistics is the process of grouping together the inflected forms of a word so they can be analysed as a single item, identified by the word's lemma, or dictionary form.
[Wikipedia: lemmatisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemmatisation)

Stemming is the process of reducing inflected (or sometimes derived) words to their word stem, base or root form—generally a written word form. The stem need not be identical to the morphological root of the word; it is usually sufficient that related words map to the same stem, even if this stem is not in itself a valid root.
[Wikipedia: stemming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming)

As for your second question, there is a package called `syn` (only for English), which contains all the synonyms, but it will create a list of all of them and for "close" or "near" that is a very long list.
Or package `qdap`, that also has a synonym function.